# WPF toggle button how to switch between 2 customized brushes

Tags: wpf, xaml, togglebutton

Hi I'm new to the WPF world.
I am working with a Toggle button and not sure how I can switch between 2 brushes.

Basically I have 2 brushes that each defines a XAML image, both of them are stored in a `ResourceDictionary`. One brush should by default shown and the other one should be shown when `IsChecked` property is true.

I kind know that I need to wrap them into styles and should use a trigger to toggle them but I am not familiar with the syntax how to do this.

What's the generic way to do this?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your question could use some more information, what did you try already?

Comment: Clarify the question: you need to change the brush of which property of which element?
And give the keys to your brushes.
For example, the ToogleButton's Background property is by default equal to such and such a brush, and with IsCheked = true - such and such.

Answer (score 0):

Generically:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Name, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 <!-Set The Brush That You Want To Use-->
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```